Google function framework cannot run structured cloud function locally
I have a Google Cloud Function written in nodejs, which I want to run with @google-cloud/functions-framework. My structure is
main_folder/ 
 test_function/ 
   index.js 
 node_modules/ 
 package.json

So as in the structure, my entry point is inside test_function/index.js. Is there a way to call that function using function framework ? or function framework does not work with folder structure (index.js has to be in the root folder) ?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.

You can run the function inside a folder after setting the path as the main in package.json. I have explained it as the answer

Apologies for misunderstanding. I missed the trick here. As you stated we can run the function inside a folder after setting the path as the main in package.json Which is stated in the Documentation

I have updated my answer by sharing the Document link and highlighting the point for not getting confused. So other community members may have a clear understanding.

Suppose your test_function/index.js file has an entry point function as follows
export async function handler(req, res) {
  return res.status(200).send("Success")
}

To run the function which is inside a folder, in the package.json set the main field as
  "main": "test_function/index.js"

And add the npm start script as
    "start": "npx @google-cloud/functions-framework --target handler"

Rememeber handler is the name of the entry point function which you export.
This will work


my entry point is inside test_function/index.js. Is there a way to call that function using function framework or function framework does not work with folder structure (index.js has to be in the root folder)

The function framework requires the index.js file to be placed in the root directory in order to recognize it as the root file. Therefore, the function framework cannot be used to call a function that is located inside any custom folder.
But as stated in the Documentation

By default, Cloud Functions attempts to load source code from a file named index.js at the root of your function directory. To specify a different main source file, use the main field in your package.json file.

You may have a look at this Documentation and Github Link for reference.
